# Unexpected UnboundLocalError for a module within nested class

Tags: python, closures, local-variables

I've inherited a legacy unit test that attempts to override the name `datetime` for a custom class nested inside of another class. I'm refactoring it now (I agree this is pretty awful) but I do not understand a particular error I am seeing.

I am seeing an `UnboundLocalError` and I can reproduce this with a self-contained example:

```
import datetime
class Foo(object):

    def inner_scope(self):

        real_datetime = datetime
        class datetime(datetime.datetime):
            @staticmethod
            def convert():
                return "blah"

        x = datetime(2012, 1, 1)
        y = x.convert()
        return x, y

f = Foo()
f.inner_scope()
```

I get this:

```
In [439]: f.inner_scope()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-439-c5053fb49b64> in <module>()
----> 1 f.inner_scope()

<ipython-input-437-222b3997ec2c> in inner_scope(self)
      3     def inner_scope(self):
      4
----> 5         real_datetime = datetime
      6         class datetime(datetime.datetime):
      7             @staticmethod

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'datetime' referenced before assignment
```

I've tried adding `print` statements to print `type(datetime)` and `type(datetime.datetime)` immediately inside of the class definition (this works) and immediately inside of the `inner_scope` definition (this fails).

By virtue of closures, shouldn't the value for `datetime` be supplied by the module that is imported, as it is checked for at higher and higher levels of scope from the `inner_scope` function?

I'm not trying to modify it either, as far as I understand, because I've seen other `UnboundLocalError` questions relating to attempts to modify variables that can be accessed via closures but not changed unless first made as local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is no different from the others you've seen related to `UnboundLocalError`.  Since your inner-class is also called `datetime` Python's bytecode compiler will mark the name `datetime` as a local variable.  Since you try to assign `real_datetime = datetime` before the class declaration you get the error.

This might be clearer if you consider that

```
class datetime(datetime.datetime):
    ...
```

is an equivalent statement to:

```
datetime = type('datetime', (datetime.datetime), {...class members...})
```

As a workaround to this sort of thing, you could always use a different name from `datetime` for the mock class.  It *probably* doesn't matter what its name is (and if it really does matter you could still override that by assigning to its `__name__` attribute after the class is created).

In Python 3 you would just declare `nonlocal datetime` like you would any other non-local variable.

Comment: So the interpreter will resolve this name first because it is a class definition, even though the class definition comes after the attempt to reassign the module to a different variable? That is, in order to predict ahead of time that this is what would have happened, I should recognize that class names are going to be resolved first? It seems very different to me than other cases of this error.

Comment: @EMS: the key is that the class definition *is* an assignment, making the compiler turn the variable `datetime` into a local variable.  It's not a question of "before" or "after" as the assignment is detected at the time the module is byte-compiled, during import.

Comment: I wouldn't say "because" it's a class definition.  What I'm saying is that defining a class is no different from any other local variable assignment where the compiler is concerned.

For example, try replacing the class definition with just something like `datetime = None`.  The compiler will see that you're creating a local variable called "datetime" and prevent it from being used anywhere in the local scope before it's been defined

Comment: I see, so it's the fact that the `class datetime...` syntax is "unpackaged" into a `datetime = ...` assignment, thus triggering the word `datetime` to be considered a local variable for this scope (before any code is run) that causes it. And to predict it, I need to be more watchful of the fact that class definitions are a particular kind of assignment statement.

Comment: The best work around I have at the moment is to re-import `datetime` in that local scope. Is declaring it `global` a better idea? Will that have any unintended side effects?

Comment: Don't declare it `global` unless you want to override the `datetime` module for the rest of that module.  That could get weird.